# bootswatch/boosttrap navbar css not showing as expected

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootswatch

I am trying to use the bootswatch journal template:
https://bootswatch.com/journal/

So I download the .css file and serve the html file using this css.. but this always ends up with a red and white navbar - which is not what I want.

I am looking for the black and white navbar as show in the page itself.

How do I go about achieving this?

thanks.

The HTML code is like so:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">title here</a>
    </div>

    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li><a href="">Add item</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->


  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You mean the color on the sub menu dropdowns when hovered over, right?

Comment: @KyleSposato: if you go down on https://bootswatch.com/journal/ you can see two styles of navbar, one white and one red.. the css always shows red and not white (the first one). I hope I am being clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace navbar-inverse in the following code with navbar-default

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
```

Comment: what you say does make sense, but where do I make this substitution?

Comment: you are a genius :) Thanks Manoj!

Comment: Thanks for the compliment but It wasn't a genius stuff

Comment: To me, that was genius stuff :)